# Simple Webserver failover

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, failover

I will be running a dynamic web site and if the server ever is to stop responding, I'd like to failover to a static website that displays a "We are down for maintenance" page. I have been reading and I found that switching the DNS dynamically may be an option, but how quick will that change take place? And will everyone see the change immediately? Are there any better ways to failover to another server?

Comment: what webserver on what OS?

Comment: Using DNS as a failover mechanism is generally not recommended.  DNS changes can take a long time to "go through" due to caching (anywhere from a minute to potentially days). 

There are much better ways to achieve what you are looking at, depending on how much control you have over the environment and the software being used?

Comment: I'm using a Windows server. (ASP.NET)

Comment: im confused.  Do you want the ability to failover & keep the site running, or do you want to display a 'down for maintenance page' if the server is down?

Comment: Do you have shared session ?

Answer (score 1):

You will find [this wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-availability_cluster#HA_Cluster_products) article very informative as it list a lot of software. Sadly I don't think that this is easy or cheaply done in Windows.

What you are wanting is something like this - [Linux HA](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Documentation) - Which, from what I understand, the servers talk to each, via internal ip's. If one goes done, then another machine from that cluster takes over control of that IP. MS has Microsoft Cluster Server (MSCS) and Microsoft's Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) for Server 2008.

Your other option is to look at using VMWare to do it, which has the same sort of failover capabilities, but then you have to buy the licensing for vmware on top of everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can run another [nginx](http://nginx.net/) as a proxy and let this machine manage the "failover". I'm also just starting with this kind of environment but it seems to become some kind of standard. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must have control of your DNS nameservers in order to specify a DNS failover service. I use a managed DNS service at ZoneEdit for my primary name server and list my hosts DNS as secondary name server. I use Zone Edit because they offer the failover service. DNSmadeeasy is another good option.

Comment: This looks interesting. I'm going to read up on their service some more to see if it will do what I need it to.

Comment: I spoke with someone at dnsmadeeasy and they said there may still be caching involved on the user side that may prevent the secondary server from being seen by everyone.  This doesn't seem like it will achieve what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) , wich is a very fast and reliable proxy. Furthermore , you can use a soft-stop trick like explained in section 4.1 of this [document](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.3/doc/architecture.txt) while doing maintenance on your server. Hope this Helps.

Comment: This is good stuff, but I don't believe that haproxy is supported on Windows???

Comment: Well sometimes that's ok, as it should run on a separate server anyway - just look at it like an appliance and disregard the operating system? ^^ (think this site, which is technically very windows-centric, uses haproxy)

Answer (score 0):

when you use a proxy which is redirecting request in case of downtime, you only change your single point of failure (spof) from the webserver to the proxy. so you definitely need a cluster software (e.g. linux-ha or mscs as mentioned by Insanity5902) or cluster hardware (e.g. two load balancers with hot failover).

dns has, besides the caching problem you already found out, a distribution delay which can be up to 24 hours. but you can use dns to do loadbalancing be giving an fqdn two ore more ip adresses. but this will not do the trick for every situation. imagine the ip is up, but your webserver is not responding, then the client will timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a proxy for that [nginx](http://www.nginx.org/) do the job for you, or may be a load balancer software tool for http protocol like [pen](http://siag.nu/pen/).
If you look for hardware solution, you can look at some appliances like [radware](http://www.radware.com/).